# Difference between Tomcat and JBoss in context of "Spring Security framework" deployment

Tags: authentication, tomcat, jboss, migration, spring-security

I have an application that use Spring-Security framework with Jboss Server. Everything works fine. I can get account locked, bad credentials messages based on the authentication.

Now, I'm trying to move to configure the same thing with Tomcat. But, I don't get account locked, bad credentials messages. I just get "Unauthorized" for every wrong authentication. Can some body point me to What I am missing ? Here is the `securitycontext.xml` file content:

```
<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="basicAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
</bean>

<bean id="filterInvocationInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="accessDecisionManager">
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref local="jaasAuthenticationProvider"/>
            <ref local="casAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you post your applicationContext-security.xml configuration? We need to see how you have setup your authentication.

Specifically the

<authentication-manager alias="authManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='userManager'/>
</authentication-manager>

and whatever the "userManager" is set to.

Comment: Stupid question but, are you logging in via the same form?  Unauthorized seems to be http basic authentication. Could you have configured that incorrectly in tomcat?